# Computer vision Read api azure

Tags: node.js, azure, ocr

I have tried Read api of azure for reading text from image/pdf (https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005/console) and it works correctly then I tried using code

```js
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze?language=en&readingOrder=basic&model-version=latest',
  'headers': {
    'Host': 'eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'key'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"url":"url"})

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log("response",response.body);
});
```

the response.body is not returning any value. Can someone help me what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by design as [the doc](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005/console) indicated:

> When you call the Read operation, the call returns with a response
> header called 'Operation-Location'. The 'Operation-Location' header
> contains a URL with the Operation Id to be used in the second step. In
> the second step, you use the Get Read Result operation to fetch the
> detected text lines and words as part of the JSON response.

The response body is empty, you can `Operation-Location` in the response header.

Just try the code below to get the `Operation-Location` and final result:

```
var request = require('request');

var region = ''
var key = ''
var imageUrl = ""

var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': `https://${region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze?language=en&readingOrder=basic&model-version=latest`,
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"url":imageUrl})

};


request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    resultURL = response.headers['operation-location'];
    //print result URL
    console.log(resultURL)

    options.url= resultURL
    options.method='GET'

    //wait 5s to allow Azure process the image
    wait(5000).then(function(){
            request.get(options,function(error, result){
                console.log(result.body)
            });
        })
});

function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
};
```

Result:

[image]